# hyper link showing outside of table

Tags: php, mysql, hyperlink

I am trying to show a table as per the screen shot below.

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaWn1.jpg)

The goal is to have the 'folder' image as a clickable link getting the link data from the MySql table.
However, when i try to do this (step by step) the hyperlinks sit outside the table. When i add  tags around the following

```
echo '<a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a>' ;
```

like this

```
echo "<td>" '<a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a>' "</td>";
```

The subsequent PHP page will not load

```
    // Attempt select query execution
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM versioncontrol";
                    if($result = mysqli_query($link, $sql)){
                        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                            
                            
                            echo "<table class='table table-bordered table-striped'>";
                                echo "<thead>";
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                        echo "<th>Image Link</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Manual Link File</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Operating Procedure ID</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Operating Procedure Name</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Operating Procedure Version</th>";
                                        echo "<th>Upload Date and Time</th>";
                                                            
                                        
                                        
                                echo "</tr>";
                                echo "</thead>";
                                echo "<tbody>";
                                
                                
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                                    echo "<tr>";
                                    
                                        echo "<td>
                                        <a href=\"sopversioncontrolKL001.php" . $record['images'] . "\" > 
                                <img src=\"images/document.jpg" . $record['images'] . "\" height=\"30\"  
    /></a></td>";
                                        
                                        echo '<a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a>' ;
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['SOP_ID'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['SOP_Name'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['SOP_Version'] . "</td>";
                                        echo "<td>" . $row['reg_date'] . "</td>";

                                  echo "</tr>";
                                }
                                echo "</tbody>";                            
                            echo "</table>";
                            // Free result set
                            mysqli_free_result($result);
                        } else{
                            echo "<p class='lead'><em>No records were found.</em></p>";
                        }
                    } else{
                        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
                    }
 
  
 
                    // Close connection
```

Comment: Place it _inside_ a `<td>`

Comment: @brombeer — That's what they are trying to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> echo "<td>" '<a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a>' "</td>";
> ```
>
> The subsequent PHP page will not load

Well, it wouldn't. That's a syntax error.

After `echo "<td>"` you need to have either a `;` or an operator.

You can't just run straight into another string literal.

Put the `<td>` and `</td>` inside the string literals you already have.

```
echo '<td><a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a></td>';
```

---

Better yet, get rid of the enormous pile of `echo` statements and just output HTML.

```
?>
    ...
    <td><a href="<?php echo $row['file']; ?>"><?php echo $row['file']; ?></a></td>
    ...
<?php
```

(You should probably make use of `htmlspecialchars` to protect yourself against stored XSS attacks too).

Comment: Thank you sir, apologies for being a newbie. Your solution makes perfect sense now. 

instead of showing the address how do I show an image i.e

Instead of 
...
    echo '<td><a href="'.$row['file'].'">'.$row['file'].'</a></td>';
...
show the image 'document.jpg where the href is replaced by the image
...
    echo "<td><a href=\"sopversioncontrolKL001.php" . $record['images'] . "\" > 
                                <img src=\"images/document.jpg" . $record['images'] . "\" height=\"30\" /></a></td>";
...